# While migrating data in rails from mysql to postgres using pgloader the created_at and updated_at fields for each table are not consistent

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have used pgloader for converting the mysql database to postgres database. The mysql database contains the valid data for both created_at and updated_at fields of each table, while the postgres database contains inconsistent data for created_at and updated_at fields. I wish to import data without having any kind of manipulation to the mysql database.

I have tried changing the code in controller and the views to get the desired output, but I think it should be feasible to change the data stored in the database instead of using conditions and adding code to controller and views.

I used

```
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
```

to create the postgres database. My database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  # pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  # timeout: 5000
  # port: 5432
  username: postgres_username
  password: postgres_password
  host: 'localhost'

development:
  <<: *default
  database: tech_login_development_mysql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 50

test:
  <<: *default
  encoding: utf8
  database: tech_login_development_mysql
  pool: 5

production:
  <<: *default
  encoding: utf8
  database: tech_login_development_mysql
  pool: 10
```

So now the tech_login_development_mysql database is created and all the migrations are executed. After creating the postgres database structure I used pgloader to load the imported mysql data. I have created a file named as database_data.load and its code is given below:

```
LOAD DATABASE
  FROM mysql://mysql_username:mysql_password@localhost/tech_login_development_mysql
  INTO postgresql://postgres_username:postgres_password@localhost/tech_login_development_mysql

ALTER SCHEMA 'tech_login_development_mysql' RENAME TO 'public';
```

After creating the above file I ran:

```
pgloader database_data.load
```

command to load the data in tech_login_development_mysql database

There is a Log table is my project whose created_at and updated_at fields in the newly created postgres database is not same as mysql database. When i ran:

```
Log.find(40124).created_at
```

Actual Result is:

```
Tue, 03 Apr 2018 08:10:04 IST +05:30
```

Expected Result is:

```
Tue, 03 Apr 2018 13:40:04 IST +05:30
```

So there is a timezone issue while migrating data from mysql to postgres, but I can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: You have to inspect actual `logs.created_at` column type both in MySQL and Pg, actual data in MySQL `logs.created_at`, default `Time.zone` for your app. Based on them, you have to either fix them OR write corresponding pgloader CAST section: https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/mysql.html

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk I referred to the link above but I can't seem to find a solution cause I have already generated the postgres table. Is there any way to modify the datetime fields of the postgres table to use timezone utc and modify time by -05:30 to get correct time which matches the corresponding mysql database

Comment: Main info I've written before the link. Please, provide that info about your environment.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/150) link to be relevant to my problem, but I could not wrap my head around its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
CAST type datetime to timestamp drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null;
```

at the end of your database_data.load